# Group Action and Orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

I am looking at the following example which says find the orbit of $0$ under addition by $2$ and $3$ if $\mathbb{Z}_4$ acts on itself by addition. So to find the orbit of $0$ we are looking at the set $\{g+0: g\in \mathbb{Z}_4\}$. So, for example if addition by $3$. Does that mean the orbit is $\{3+0\}=\{3\}$?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orbit will be the entire $\mathbb Z_4$ under addition by 3, since if you add 3 to 0, you are getting 3, if you are adding it once more, then you are getting 2, etc. so you can get any element of $\mathbb Z_4$ from 0 just by adding 3s.

If you are adding 2s to 0, then you will get just 0 and 2, so in this case the orbit will be $\{0,2\}$.